# How to sort list of shapes by their area in Java

Tags: java, collections

I have created a list of Objects and added elements such as Circle and Square in it. I have added a method in the sqaure and circle classes which checks the instance of the object and compares the area.

```
public class Circle extends Shape implements Comparable <Object>{   
    public int compareTo(Object otherObject) { 

      double difference=0.0;
      int retValue= 3;

      if(otherObject instanceof Circle){
         Circle circle= (Circle)otherObject;
         difference= this.area()- circle.area();   //calculate the difference of areas
      }             
      if(otherObject instanceof Square){
         Square square= (Square)otherObject; //Casting the object to Sqaure 
         difference= this.area()- square.area();//Calculate difference of Areaareas
      }  

      if(difference == 0.0)retValue = 0;                 //return 0 if area is equal
      if(difference < Shape.TOLERANCE)retValue = -1;     //return -1 if area of the circle is less than the otherObject
      if(difference > Shape.TOLERANCE)retValue = 1;      //return 1 if area of the circle is more than the otherObject

      return retValue;       
    }
}
```

My class where I want to sort this looks like this:-

```
 List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

when, I am trying `Collections.sort(objectList)`, it is giving me an me error

```
  no suitable method found for sort(List<Object>)
```

Any suggestions. Also I have declared my class like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apples vs. Oranges, or in your case Circles vs. Squares.

You need to make them share a common aspect, which means that you need to make them implement a `Shape2D` interface with a `double getArea()` method.

You can then write a `Comparator<Shape2D>` and call `sort(myShapeList, myAreaComparator)`.

**Update**

Given the extra code now shown in question, you already have the common base class `Shape`, which appears to have an `abstract double area()` method, implemented by both `Circle` and `Square`.

You then change `Shape` to be `Comparable<Shape>` (not `Object`), and the `compareTo()` method, which now takes a `Shape` as parameter, can call `area()` without any casting.

Comment: Hi.. Sorry I am new to java so questions might come as obvious-  1. If I am  using `Comparable` so I shouldn't need to specify the type?  2. I did not understand the the third part of your answer. For the second part, my Circle and Square class extend shape class which has area method in it, so how will I use it now.

Comment: You remove `Comparable` and `compareTo()` from `Circle`, and instead add `Comparable<Shape>` to `Shape` and implement `int compareTo(Shape that)` there. Assuming `area()` is an abstract method on `Shape`, you can call it without having to cast to `Circle` or `Square`.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense for a `Circle` to be comparable to `Object`.

If you want to sort circles and squares by their area,
use a `Comparator` instead.

It will also make sense to:

- Use a `List<Shape>` rather than a `List<Object>`
- A `Comparator<Shape>` can do the job, using `Shape.area` for the ordering
- Use `Double.compare` to compare the areas, instead of manual if-else

Something like this:

```
public void demo() {
    List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<>();
    shapes.add(new Circle(2));
    shapes.add(new Square(2));
    shapes.add(new Square(1));
    shapes.add(new Circle(1));
    Collections.sort(shapes, new Comparator<Shape>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Shape o1, Shape o2) {
            return Double.compare(o1.area(), o2.area());
        }
    });
    System.out.println(shapes);
}
```

Where the implementation of `Shape`, `Circle`, `Square` can be simple like this:

```
abstract class Shape {
    abstract double area();
}

class Circle extends Shape {
    private final double radius;

    Circle(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    @Override
    double area() {
        return radius * radius * Math.PI;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Circle(" + radius + ")";
    }
}

class Square extends Shape {

    private final double side;

    Square(double side) {
        this.side = side;
    }

    @Override
    double area() {
        return side * side;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Square(" + side + ")";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use the comparator approach I proposed?

Comment: well tbh its a requirement for my project. how can I find median of circle and square separately by this method? Should I create more lists of square and circle?

Comment: Also please take a look at this post [link](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/109389/check-if-one-shape-is-in-another-shape)

Comment: The code I have you does what you described. After the list of shapes is sorted, you can get the median with `shapes.get(shapes.size() / 2)`

Comment: but that would be the median for the whole shape.. whereas I want median for individual shapes, i.e., Circle area median and Square area median

Comment: Then you can put the different shapes in separate lists, and get the median objects separately